# slurm with JSON output - version update required?

Tags: json, slurm

the slurm commands provide a json output option, for example:

"--json
Dump job information as JSON. All other formating and filtering arugments will be ignored. "
Source: https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html#OPT_json

On ubuntu 20.04 with slurm 19.05, this option is not recognized.
"squeue: unrecognized option '--json'"

Is it available on later releases?
If required, can I update the slurm version (installed from the ubuntu 20.04 repository) ?

Answer (score 2):

Beware that the online documentation is always valid for the latest stable version. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/NEWS#L307) this option was introduced in version 21.08.